# CameraX blurry when setting LinearZoom below 0.5f and fails to focus on Pixel 6a/7

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

Why is the camera preview blurry when `cameraControl#setLinearZoom` is called with a value of less than `0.5`?

I'm testing on a Pixel 6a and Pixel 7.

As soon as I hardcode this to `0.5f`, the camera preview is no longer blurry.

This only seems to be happening on Pixel 6a and 7. On Samsung Galaxy A51, the images starts off blurry, but quickly focuses.

```
 val seekBarChangeListener = object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            val dividend = progress.toFloat()
            val divisor = seekBar.max.toFloat()
            val quotient = dividend/divisor 

            // when quotient is < 0.5f, the camera preview is blurry
            cameraControl?.setLinearZoom(quotient)
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Tracking issue here -  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/293980130